# How can I make the edit-mode field type of one material-table column dependent upon the value of another column, without affecting other rows?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

**Summary**

I need the input field that appears when the user is in edit mode to be different depending on the value of a different column for that row. E.g. if the user is in edit mode and `Column X` has value `A`, then `Column Y` should be a text entry field. If, however, `Column X` has value `B`, then `Column Y` should be a dropdown select list. Importantly, this must not affect any other rows (i.e. the fact that `Column Y` might be a text entry field for this row should not affect the input type on any other row).

**Mockup**

In case it wasn’t clear what I was asking for, here is a mockup that shows the functionality I’m after.

***1. Target type is 'Group', so 'Target' field is numeric entry***
[image]

***2. Target type is 'Address', so 'Target' field is a select list of strings.*** Notice that the other rows entries are
unaffected (i.e. they are still numeric fields)
[image]

**More detail**

I am creating a lighting control app, and am using material-table as the means through which users specify what actions a button can take (it could be a single action, in which case the table would be a single row, or many actions, in which case the table would be many rows). They can either control a single device, which is stored in a database and should be selectable from a dropdown list, or a group of devices, in which case they manually enter the number of the group they wish to control.

**Code**

This code forms the basis of the mockups (above):

```
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

const devices = ["Device A (Stairs)", "Device B (Hallway)"];

export default class ControlSpecificationTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columns: [
        { title: 'Step', field: 'step' },
        { title: 'Target Type', field: 'target_type', lookup: { 0: 'Address', 1: 'Group' } },
        { title: 'Target', field: 'target', initialEditValue: '0', lookup: { 0: devices[0], 1: devices[1] }},
        // { title: 'Target', field: 'target', initialEditValue: '0', type:'numeric'},

        {
          title: 'Control Type',
          field: 'control_type',
          lookup: { 0: 'Button', 1: 'Slider', 2: 'Arrows' },
        },
        {
            title: 'Command type',
            field: 'command_type',
            lookup: { 0: 'Arc level', 1: 'Minimum', 2: 'Maximum' }
        }, 
        {
            title: 'Command Value',
            field: 'command_value',
        },
        {
            title: 'Time Until Next Command (seconds)',
            field: 'time_until_next_command',
        }
      ],
      data: [
        { step: '1', target_type: 1, target: 1, control_type: 0, command_type: 0, command_value: 23, time_until_next_command: 3 },
        { step: '2', target_type: 1, target: 15, control_type: 1, command_type: 1, command_value: "N/A", time_until_next_command: 1 },
        { step: '3', target_type: 1, target: 13, control_type: 1, command_type: 1, command_value: "N/A", time_until_next_command: 1 },

      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <>
        <MaterialTable
            title="Control Steps"
            columns={this.state.columns}
            data={this.state.data}
            editable={
                {
                onRowAdd: newData =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        resolve();
                    }),
                onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) => {
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        resolve();
                    })
                    },
                onRowDelete: oldData => 
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        resolve();
                    }),
                }
            }
        />
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to keep track of the currently selected target_type and override the editComponent of the columns to show either the drop down or the textField:

```
 editComponent: t =>
        this.currentEditingTarget === 0 ? (
          <Select
            value={t.value}
            onChange={e => {
              t.onChange(e.target.value);
              console.group(e.target.value);
              this.currentEditingTarget = e.target.value;
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value={0}>{devices[0]}</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={1}>{devices[1]}</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        ) : (
          <TextField
            value={t.value}
            onChange={e => t.onChange(e.target.value)}
            type="numeric"
          />
        ),
```

Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-darkness-qw16o).